# Clicking JS Tabs Causes Browser to Scroll Up

Tags: javascript

**EDIT: I found why it is doing this, but a question has now arisen from this.
Scroll down to where I said "edit" at the bottom to help me with the new issue that has come up.**

The page can be seen here: http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/bathroom/swanstone-bath-and-alcove-walls.php

If you scroll down to the bottom and click one of the tabs underneath the section "video" it jumps up the page.  It only happens if you scroll down so the video is above the bottom of your browser.

Here is the page code that I have for the tabs:

```
        <ul id="tabs" class="filter-nav option-set">
          <li><a class="selected" href="#">Acetone Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Impact Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Heat Test</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-items" class="margin_top_55 textcenter">
          <hr class="dashed margin_bottom_15">
          <section>
            <div>
              <p>
                <video id="sublime" class="sublime center" poster="/resource/video/bathroom/tub-and-shower/modular/swanstone/swanstone-chemical-test.jpg" width="640" height="320" data-name="Swanstone - Chemical (Acetone) Test" data-uid="56410b5b" preload="auto">
                <source src="/resource/video/bathroom/tub-and-shower/modular/swanstone/swanstone-chemical-test.mov" />
                </video>
              </p>
              <h3>Acetone Test</h3>
              <h5 class="grey">Impervious To Chemicals</h5>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section>
            <div>
              <p>
                <video id="sublime2" class="sublime center" poster="/resource/video/bathroom/tub-and-shower/modular/swanstone/swanstone-impact-test.jpg" width="640" height="320" data-name="Swanstone - Impact Test" data-uid="12be3c75" preload="auto">
                <source src="/resource/video/bathroom/tub-and-shower/modular/swanstone/swanstone-impact-test.mov" />
                </video>
              </p>
              <h3>Impact Test</h3>
              <h5 class="grey">Impact Resistant!</h5>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section>
            <div>
              <p>
                <video id="sublime3" class="sublime center" poster="/resource/video/bathroom/tub-and-shower/modular/swanstone/swanstone-heat-test.jpg" width="640" height="320" data-name="Swanstone - Heat Test" data-uid="403140c8" preload="auto">
                <source src="/resource/video/bathroom/tub-and-shower/modular/swanstone/swanstone-heat-test.mov" />
                </video>
              </p>
              <h3>Heat Test</h3>
              <h5 class="grey">Withstands Heat!</h5>
            </div>
          </section>
```

and here is the JS code that I have

```
$(function() { 
    $("#tabs").tabs("#tab-items section", { effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 0, fadeInSpeed: 400 }); 
    $(".option-set").on("click", "a", function(e) { 
    $(this).addClass('selected') .parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass('selected'); }); 
});
```

It calls out to jquery.tools.min.js which is just the "tabs" of the jqueryUI.  That file can be seen here: http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/resource/js/jquery.tools.min.js

**EDIT: Fixed Issue on my own, but have a question now for best method**

It seems to be a problem with the div going hidden instantly, and the other fading in, so this code right here:

```
{ effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 0, fadeInSpeed: 400 });
```

So the issue is that even though it's impossible to see, both sections go invisible for like .0000 MS but it is forced to push the page up there is nothing there (if you know what I mean).

So I can fix this by changing the "fadeOutSpeed" from 0 to 1, and it no longer does this, although it does look a little goofy.  Is there a better effect to use which would stop this from happening?  It appears as if having a fade does this problem.

Thanks for the help guys! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your own code in custom.js:

```
$('.navbar a, .scroll a, .smoothscroll a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null (repeated 4 times)
        }, 850,'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
        if you don't want to use the easing effects:
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        */
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

The buttons are $('.smoothscroll a'), so your scrollTop makes it scroll top!

Comment: Hmm.. I tried deleting that entire script and checking the page, yet it still happened? /:

Comment: I have the same thing working right here: http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/bathroom/sterling-accord.php The only difference is that the one I am having issues with is close to the bottom of the page.  It's as if the div goes hidden instantly and the bottom of the page moves up, moving the screen up.  It has to be something of this nature as you can make the same thing happen on the working one, only if you zoom out the page far enough so the footer shows.

Comment: EDIT: Found out what was causing the issue, but now something else has arisen from it.  I fixed the OP to show the new issue.  Please check it out and let me know if you know of a better way to execute this,  Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Yep, that would do it.  I do wish that I could have it fade though without being jumpy.  The fade looks nicer /:  Thanks though, I guess I'll just use that until i find a fade that doesn't glitch like that.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your update. Put style="height:423px;" in your "tab-items" div.

Comment: Okay, interesting fix.  Although I am using the tabs in a general sense, and not every block is going to that tall.  I guess I could just add it to that one div in-particular, which has the same effect, although that just means every time I have to add an additional class with a different height for each.  I understand now why most sites use the "default" instead of "fade".  Very interesting, thanks for your help, this explains a lot.  Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this scrollfix can fix it?

```js
$(".option-set").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass('selected');
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just use divs or spans instead of a tags. Then just use css to style it to look like a link.

**Example:**

```
myclass {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```